# Retrieve the value of a Slider and send it to MySQL

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a online survey app in flutter and the API in PHP with MySQL for the database.

I'm using **TextFormField** for the **Name field** and wanted to use **Slider** for **Age field**.
I can retrieve the value from TextFormField using `onSaved: (e) => name = e,`, But I don't know how to retrieve the value of the `Slider`.

I tried to change the value to string using `age.toString()` but It says:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type.

Here is my **Form()** code:

```
Form(
   key: _key,
   child: ListView(
      children: [
         TextFormField(
            onSaved: (e) => name = e,
            decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Name"),
         ),
         Slider(
            min: 10,
            max: 100,
            value: age,
            onChanged: (value) {
               setState(() {
                  age = value;
               });
            },
            label: "$age",
         ),
         MaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
               check();
            },
            child: Text("submit"),
         )
      ]
   )
),
```

Comment: [Sliders demystified](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-sliders-demystified-4b3ea65879c)